# Getting last element on click every time in Javascript loop with Phaser JS

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am making a game in Phaser although I believe the core of this issue is a lack of my JS understanding.

I am looping through a Phaser container and wish to apply a click handler on each child sprite, but when I execute the click on any of the sprites, it always returns the last child.

I have tried various suggestions on Stack Overflow eg here: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

but can never get the click to return anything other than the last item.

An Example:

```
let items = //my container with 4 child sprites to click on
let i = 0;
item.list.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.setInteractive();
    (function(i) {
        obj.on('pointerdown', function(i){
            console.log(i);
        }.bind(this, i));
    })(i);
    i++;
});
```

In this example, every sprite I click on outputs '3' tot he console, when it should output 0,1,2 or 3 depending on which was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is abit complicated. If you just want to add a EventHandler just, you don't need an extra closure. Just check the code below, for a leaner approach

**Working example:**

```js
// Minor formating for stackoverflow
    document.body.style = "display: flex;flex-direction: column;";    

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 536,
        height: 183,
        scene: {
            create
        },
        banner: false
    }; 

    function create () {
        let items = this.add.container(10, 10);
        items.add(this.add.sprite(20, 20, 'sprite'));
        items.add(this.add.sprite(20, 60, 'sprite'));
        items.add(this.add.sprite(20, 100, 'sprite'));
        items.list.forEach(function(obj, index) {
            obj.setInteractive();
            obj.on('pointerdown', function(){
                console.log(`You clicked: sprite with index ${index}`);
            }, this); // although I don't know why you would want do bind this "this"
       });
    }

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js">
</script>
```

> - Here the docs to the `forEach` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach, explains the `index` used
> - Here the docs to the Phaser `on` listener https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html#on__anchor, explains the passing of the context.

Comment: Thanks, the complexity is the result of suggestions in the thread I linked to. I had started with your example and it always returns '3' for the index. I'm guessing it must be something deeper in the application causing it than this snippet.

Comment: @web_la my example doesn't always returns '3'. here is a full working example.

Comment: I update the answer

Comment: Turns out my specific problem was I had part of an invisible png overlaying everything with the index of three which was always getting clicked. 

Answer is technically correct of course